# PHP to find specific thing in an array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array

```
Array (
    [0] => "8266_hal_url"
    [1] => "8266_hal_picture"
    [2] => "8266_hal_status" 
    [3] => "8266_hal_qwert"
    [4] => "4224423_hal_status"
    [5] => "4223_hal_status"
)
```

How do I find all `hal_status` in an array and pass it to a query?

Comment: Try experimenting with the [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP >= 5.3.0

```
$testData = array ( '8266_hal_url',
                    '8266_hal_picture',
                    '8266_hal_status',
                    '8266_hal_qwert',
                    '4224423_hal_status',
                    '4223_hal_status',
                  );
$testNeedle = 'hal_status';

$result = array_filter($testData, function($arrayEntry) use ($testNeedle) { 
  return (strpos($arrayEntry,$testNeedle) !== false); 
});

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: There's plenty of methods: strpos() and substr(), str_replace(), etc... but that's asking another question entirely, so shouldn't be answered simply in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=array();
foreach ($myarray as $element)
  if (strpos($element,'hal_status')===false) continue;
  else $result[]=$element;

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Haven't heard of `instr()`. Also the `continue` is unnecessary, simply switch the condition.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck:It say's call to undefined function instr().output should be 8266_hal_status,4224423_hal_status,4223_hal_status

Comment: instr wasn't a valid PHP function last time I checked

Comment: Sorry, fingers faster than brain syndome: `instr()` is NOT a PHP function but one of our standard library functions. Edited to `strpos()` as it should be

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $item)
{
    if(strpos($item, 'hal_status') !== false)
    {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```